# SUM of vales of ID's if multiple attributes in diffenet sheets matches in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I need the formula for `"If both columns (GRADE,FINISH,THICKNESS,WIDTH,HEIGHT) are maches sum of the count in the "NO" column should appear in "PURCHASE" column."`  Here the condition is same (GRADE,FINISH,THICKNESS,WIDTH,HEIGHT) may appear many times in that case the vales of same attribute should add and it will be calculated in column `"PURCHASE"` the red in the image u can see. So we get the stock of individual product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF(A2&B2&C2&D2&E2=Sheet1!A2&Sheet1!B2&Sheet1!C2&Sheet1!D2&Sheet1!E2,Sheet1!G2,"")
```

other way you can concatenate columns in both the sheets to new column, and Match

```
"=INDEX(Sheet1!G:G,MATCH(F2,Sheet1!I:I,0))"  

GRADE   FINISH  THICKNESS   WIDTH   HEIGHT  Concatenate  
12       13          14      15       16    A2&B2&C2&D2&E2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Punith. The thing is both red and green are in same sheet. I have used this formula to get the values =SUMIFS($H$3:$H$20, $B$3:$B$20, H28,$C$3:$C$20, I28,$D$3:$D$20, J28,$E$3:$E$20, K28,$F$3:$F$20, L28)